# How should I attach a patch piece of wallboard?

Tags: drywall

There's a hole in our ceiling near the vent fan. I plan to cut a piece of wallboard to fit, then patch the sides with that plaster type goop. How should I attach the wallboard?

I was thinking I could nail it to the wood up there then cover the nails with the goop. Or maybe I could glue it to the wood.

[image]

Comment: are you going to patch your air/vapor barrier?  normally you just put a piece of wood up on each of the joints and use drywall screws to secure the wood to the existing and then the new patch to the wood.

Comment: Is that that bit of plastic in there upper right?

Comment: yes the plastic is 6mil poly and generally used as a vb/ab.  if you don't have it then moisture laden air goes through the insulation layer hits a cold surface and condenses allowing mold to grow.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info. I don't think it was all the way there to begin with, as there were some... ahem... irregularities when we moved in. I'll take a look at this, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut a piece of drywall (wallboard) to size.

Use drywall screws (4 of them) about 1.5 inch long and screw the drywall into the wood beams.

Plaster to hide the gap.

Comment: Plaster, or joint compound?